# Appium iOS throws "An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript" when typing

Tags: javascript, ios, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I have a register screen with 2 textfields for height and weight. I did sendkeys successfully for height, but then I always get exception for the second textfield. I am using Appium 1.4.13. My code is below:

```
// click to enter height
iosDriver.findElementsByClassName("UIATextField").get(0).click();
// enter height => successfully sendkeys
iosDriver.findElementsByClassName("UIAPickerWheel").get(0).sendKeys("180");
// click to enter weight
iosDriver.findElementsByClassName("UIATextField").get(1).click();
// enter weight => always throws exception
iosDriver.findElementsByClassName("UIAPickerWheel").get(0).sendKeys("77");
```

and the exception is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 1.18 seconds

I don't have a workaround for this situation. Any help much appreciated

Comment: could you please share the complete exception stacktrace and the more from server logs as well

Comment: I am not an iOS dev but why are you sending values to Picker Wheel?

Comment: it automates user's action to enter value to picker wheel